# Graphical artifacts in eclipse - Linux Mint - Eclipse Mars

Tags: linux, eclipse, screen, eclipse-mars, amd-gpu

I'm using the following configuration:

```
Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 2.8.6
kernel 3.19.0-32-generic
AMD Radeon R5 M330
driver: xserver-xorg-video-ati v 1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1
Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200
```

When I scroll the page I obtain this graphical problem (you can see the code duplicated, I imagine is a refresh problem of the GPU):
[image: The graphical artifact]

How can I solve the problem? I also tried to used `fglrx-updates v. 2:15.200`, but i didn't solve anything

I also tried to use an external monitor (Samsung screen 23" connected via HDMI) instead of the laptop screen but the problem doesn't goes away.

Comment: Because I note the same problem on my computer, we can consider that is not linked to your hardware configuration or eclipse. I am getting the problem on sublime text. However, we are both working on Mint 17.3

Comment: @SnP so how have you solved this? It's a bit problematic to work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be related to libgtk3 usage in Linux Mint which is somewhat incompatible with Eclipse.
I had the same problem and I cured it adding:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

in eclipse.ini **before** `--launcher.appendVmargs`.

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the whole story as I still have "strange" crashes, but might be JavaFX-related, so YMMV.

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thank you!